# A cute question on group action

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a subgroup of $S_n$ that acts transitively on $(1,2,...,n)$. Let $N$ be a non trivial normal subgroup of $G$. Does $N$ act transitively on the set? Its true when $n$ is prime.

Comment: I meant on the set.Extremely sorry for the careless mistake.

Comment: Yeah actually i edited p to n...its true for prime....i made a mistake while editing the question

Comment: This is Example $3.11$ in Keith Conrad's text [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/transitive.pdf). I suppose it is not true in general.

Comment: Yeah I want an explicit counterexample if there is one.

Comment: Examples are not exactly hard to find! Groups of order $4$ with $n=4$ for example. What is true is that the orbits of $N$ all have the same length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take any non-simple group $A$, and let it act on itself by left translations. If $A$ has $n$ elements, this allows you to think of $A$ as a subgroup of $S_n$. Now consider any proper non-trivial normal subgroup $B$ of $A$.

Comment: This shows that pretty much **any** group is a counterexample.

Answer (score 3):

This is not true in general - it won't be true for any non-prime Abelian group for example. I'll use $C_4$ (cyclic group with 4 elements) to demonstrate.

$C_4$ can be identified as the subgroup of $S_4$ generated by $(1,2,3,4)$. This is clearly transitive and has normal subgroup generated by $(1,3)(2,4)$ which has two distinct orbits.

However if you further assume that $G$ is primitive, then $N$ must act transitively.